# Multiple Key Detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working on a way to make keyboard shortcuts. Initially I had done this:

```
function clicking(e) {  

    var code;

    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);

        if(character == 'X' && e.ctrlKey) {
            window.location = 'http://www.example.org/';            
        } 

}
```

Where the user would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> to redirect, or perhaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. This works fine on windows of course, but on a Mac I'm having some problems. This was the simplest solution and I didn't want to overcomplicate it. On top of that my brain isn't functioning perfectly today, and I was wondering if there was any way around this on a Mac.

I want to keep the user experience the same throughout platforms.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter with OS you're using, but which *browser*.

Comment: No but on a Mac it doesn't work in Firefox or Opera, so clearly the OS is coming into consideration here.

Comment: Works for me, but to be clear `ctrlKey` does affect the ‘ctrl’ key specifically, and not the command key (⌘) more commonly used for keyboard shortcuts on the Mac. (Except in ancient IE5/mac.)

Comment: are you sure? I know it works in chrome on a Mac but I cant get it working in Opera or Firefox. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a plugin?

http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/